# How do I convert an abbreviated integer into an integer, in a string, in Java?

Tags: java, integer, equation, equation-solving

I have the following string as my input:

```
(100m/10k) * 10k
```

where

```
m = 1,000,000
k = 1,000
```

I expect an output of

```
(100000000/10000) * 10000
```

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to replace the abbreviated integers with "real integers". I've tried looping through each of the characters in the string and finding the letters that have a corresponding integer and multiplying them with the integer before it, but I'm having trouble with finding the integer before the letter, and replacing/inserting it in the correct spot.

Comment: Can't you just `replace("m", "000000")` and so on?

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, thank you.

Comment: Are you likely to have numbers like `2.5k` which has to become `2500`?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your expressions you might consider writing a parser to evaluate the expression in postFix notation.  Then as you encounter `k,m`, or even `g` you can push the appropriate value on the stack with the multiplicative operator.  This would also take care of @DawoodibnKareem's question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.